# Reuse property with version number when adding a dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, build, dependencies, sbt

I have a project built with sbt 0.11.
I'm trying to create a simple UI with Scala Swing, so first thing is to add a dependency on scala-swing in my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.1-1"
```

But I have a SettingKey scalaVersion defined:

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.1-1"
```

How can I reference that property? If I try to use it like

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % scalaVersion
```

Compiler complains that it found sbt.SettingKey[String] while String is expected. There are methods `get(...)` and `evaluate(...)` on SettingKey but they require some Setting[Scope] parameter to be passed in.

What is the simplest way to just reference this property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the system that `libraryDependencies` now depends on `scalaVersion`:

```
libraryDependencies <+= (scalaVersion) { sv => "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % sv }
```

(that's my preferred formatting; it's actually invoking the `apply` method on `scalaVersion` so you could write it a few different ways, e.g., `scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % _)`.)

If you had multiple settings you wanted to depend on simultaneously, you'd apply on the tuple of them:

```
foo <<= (scalaVersion, organization) { (sv, o) => o + " uses Scala " + sv }
```

Comment: Thanks for telling the alternatives. I always feel that SBT is overcomplicated.

Comment: SBT 1.4.7 says `error: `` `<+=` operator is removed. Try `lhs += { x.value }` ``. Using `scalaVersion.value` works.

Answer (score 3):

```
libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % _)
```

The `<` tells SBT that your setting has a dependency on another setting.

The `+` tells SBT that you want to add another value, not replace the existing ones (also, it indicates the the contents of the setting are a sequence, and you are adding one element to it).

The syntax `setting(function)` is the same as `function(setting)`, where `function` takes a setting evaluated at the proper context as parameter. I don't even know how to write that, and it would be very verbose, so the shortcut is very helpful.

One can also use `(setting 1, setting 2)((a, b) => ... )` to make dependencies on multiple settings.

PS: The following might works as well, and it is a bit shorter, but it has been deprecated without special compiler flags as of 2.10.0.

```
libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" %)
```

Answer (score 3):

Realising this is old - adding an answer in case anyone else comes across it.
Just add `.value` to the `scalaVersion` variable to get the string value:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % scalaVersion.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion { v => "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % v}
```

should work.